# How to simulate subdomain and subsubdomain locally with host file?

Tags: php, localhost

For testing blogs locally with sub and sub sub domin I have put in host file

```
127.0.0.1 sub1.domain.com
sub2.127.0.0.1 sub2.sub1.domain.com
```

but it works only for the first one.
Is it possible to make both work somehow ?

Comment: How exactly is the second one supposed to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you enter the hosts don't append text to ip address

```
> 127.0.0.1 sub1.domain.com
> 127.0.0.1 sub2.sub1.domain.com
```

Comment: And add virtualhosts to your apache